# Black screen when activity starts inside of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a `Fragment` which extends `Fragment` . Inside this `Fragment` I have a button which opens an `Activity`. The code for the `OnClickListener` of this button is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The `ActivityTwo` opens correctly but until to open appears a black screen. I want, until opened the `ActivityTwo`, fragment to exists as background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` in my theme solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition (0, 0);
```

Comment: In ActivityTwo i have animations when activity opens and when activity closes.

Comment: Try adding overridePendingTransition (0, 0); in onCreate() of 2nd activity

Comment: I add overridePendingTransition (0, 0); below  from super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); and above from setContent but doesn't work... still black screen..

Comment: Also I add it  after setContent but still black screen

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:windowDisablePreview` in your styles.xml file:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- This disables the black preview screen -->
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: My theme is name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: Of course I had tried to add the line <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item> in my theme but it doesn't work...